# What does Linux refer to?

Tags: linux

A naive question maybe but what does Linux refer to?

I was reading an article ([Android Authority](https://www.androidauthority.com/an-introduction-to-python-on-android-759685/)) and it said "if you want to create APKs then I recommend using Linux instead".

Here is my understanding:

- Windows is a proprietary OS from Microsoft
- Mac is a proprietary OS (based on Unix) from Apple

When someone tells me to use Linux which version of Linux is he referring to Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian, ...

Thanks

Comment: Linux strictly refers to the kernel (the same kernel which runs on Android devices). However usually the term means a system with Linux kernel and GNU userspace, cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux)

Comment: The article you cite has the opinion that Android development with Python is better on a Linux desktop (compared to directly on Android, apparently). That has very little to do with Linux as an OS, as many of the components are cross platform, and Linux has many distros and flavors. They just like a particular set of tools.

Comment: Would it mean that a binary will run on all flavours of Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Linux in narrow sense means **only** [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel).

Linux in wider sense means full software environment running on Linux kernels,
e.g. one on multitude [Linux distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution).

As usual: one word a few significantly different meanings (based on context).